# How to Change colour of an object

Tags: materials

I have tried creating a standard intro but while using materials it's not showing the result in color [image: here I have used red on M but it's not changing] I have chosen instead it results in gray color only.

Comment: We-ll need to see your Blend file to see exactly what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to add the link into your question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you have the objects Viewport Display set to "Display As" Wire instead of Textured?

[image]